# Selecting Item in DropDownList produces new form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

well I have four departments in my dropdownlist, I want it to be like, when I select the required item in the dropdownlist it should open the registration form of that department.

```
    <div class="form-group string department">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3>
          Select Department
        </label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
        @{
            List<SelectListItem> deplist = new List<SelectListItem>();
            deplist.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Department A" });
            deplist.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Department B" });
            deplist.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Department C" });
            deplist.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "Department D" });
          }
           @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Department, deplist, "--Select Department -", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
```

my views are like this
DOP department

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group string required patient_regno">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">
        Regestration No
        </label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegistrationNo, new { placeholder = "BX1234", @class = "string required form-control" })
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistrationNo, null, new { @class = "text-error" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group string required patient_regdate">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
     Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegistrationDate, new{@class="string required form-control", type="date"})
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegistrationDate, null, new { @class = "text-error" })</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

other department is DOT

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group string patient_onsetdate">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">
            Onset Date
            </label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OnsetDate, new { @class = "string form-control", type = "date", size = "50" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group patient_onset">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
         Onset Place</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OnsetAt, new { @class = "string form-control", placeholder = "Place", type = "text" })
        </div>
        </div>
```

I have created views for different departments how can I open them as a form on the current view when I select an item from DropDownList?

Comment: So what problems are you having?

Comment: the problem is that I have created views for different departments how can I open them as a form on the current view when I select an item from dropdownlist....

Comment: If you want to stay on the same page, then you need ajax to post the value to a controller method that returns a partial view and then update the DOM

Comment: yes I want to stay on the same page, can you help me how can i do that @StephenMuecke

Comment: You need to do a bit of research (start [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)). But add a `<div id="placeholder"></div>` to your view and then add a script to handle the dropdown's change event - `$('#Department').change(function() { $.get('@Url.Action("yourAction", "yourController")', { id: $(this).val() }, function(data) { $('#placeholder').html(data); }); })` and have you method return a partial view of the form you want to display.

Comment: i tried but didn't get any results. I just updated my Question can you help me now! @StephenMuecke

Comment: You update does not show any scripts at all.